# SciPy Cumulative Distribution Function Plotting

Tags: python, cdf

I am having troubles plotting a Cumulative Distribution Function.

So far I Have found this:

```
scipy.stats.beta.cdf(0.2,6,7)
```

But that only gives me a point.

This will be what I use to plot:

```
pylab.plot()
pylab.show()
```

What I want it to look like is this:
[File:Binomial distribution cdf.svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3aBinomial_distribution_cdf.svg&page=1)

with `p = .2` and the bounds stopping once `y = 1` or close to 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first argument to `cdf` can be an array of values,  rather than a single value. It will then return an array of values.

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,20,100)
cdf = stats.binom.cdf
plt.plot(x,cdf(x, 50, 0.2))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you soo much! I spent about 3 hours trying to work up to something like this.

But I'm still having a hard time understanding this conceptually. What is this linspace(0,20,100)

As for the stat.beta.cdf was I just using the wrong code?
I see you used stats.binom.cdf

Comment: [np.linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)(0,20,100) creates a numpy array of 100 evenly spaced values between 0 and 20 (inclusive). (Try `print(np.linspace(0,20,10))`. It pays to experiment!)

Comment: Since you posted a link to a graph of a binomial cdf, I used [stats.binom.cdf](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom.html) instead of [stats.beta.cdf](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html).

Comment: i still am confused about how the stats.binom.cdf(x,50,0.2) works... I understand the x can be an array and i understand my p = 0.2 but why 50? I have played with the numbers and have went to the manual but it still don't make sense...

Comment: On the [doc page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom.html) you'll see an example using `binom.cdf(x, n, p)`. The `x` can be any array-like object. `n` is the number of tosses, and `p` is the probability of success. The meanings of the parameters can be understood by looking at [the source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.11.0/scipy/stats/distributions.py) and matching it up with this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the user above, ubuntu, has suggested the right function to use. 
Actually his answer is very much misleading and incorrect at large.

Note that `binom.cdf()` is a function to calculate the cdf of a binomial distribution specified by n and p, `Binomial(n,p)`. That's to say it returns values of the cdf of that random variable for each value in x, rather than the actual cdf function for the discrete distribution specified by vector x.

To calculate cdf for any distribution defined by vector x, just use the `histogram()` function:

```
import numpy as np
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(np.random.randint(0,10,100), normed=True)
cdf = cumsum(hist)
```

or, just use the `hist()` plotting function from matplotlib.

Comment: Agree with you comment. Your solution is the valid one, the other one only applies to binomial distribution